How to use bound function as Proc in Ruby
I'm new to ruby, and I'm trying to read a simple CSV file.
I can do this
File.read("info.csv")
    .split[1..]
    .map {|it|it.split(",")}

But I'd like to know if there's something like this to replace the last line
.map String.split.bind(',')

I've tried to find a .split function in the String class, but perhaps that only exists in class instances.
I've also heard about message passing, so I searched ruby pass message as proc, but I don't know enough nomeclature to get actually usefull results.

"I'm trying to read a simple CSV file" – use Ruby's built-in CSV library!

BTW, [1..] will skip the first character, not the first line.

Thank you, in the future I will, rn I'm learning ruby

@Stefan I put if after the split and came back here to edit the code, but people had already answered! TY tho, I'll edit the question

When learning Ruby, make sure to check out the standard library, it has many more useful and interesting classes. CSV is just one of them.

You can do something like this
split_proc = ->(str) { str.split(",") }

File.read("info.csv")[1..] # read file & skip header
    .split
    .map(&split_proc)


Thank you very much!
I know how to inline this, but is there a way to exclude the explicit argument?
Kinda like kotlin?

@Manse sure you can use numbered block arguments -> { _1.split(",")} but IMO it detracts from readability.
